# Lighttpd rewrite for Codeigniter breaking on certain URLs

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, lighttpd, codeigniter-2

I moved from apache to lighttpd, and since then certain URLs break the rewriting and give 404. No details in access.log, error.log regarding what actual URL was hit.

These kind work:
http://192.168.1.250/loop/rest/admin

But not these:
http://192.168.1.250/loop/rest/admin/logs/file::log-2012-02-14.php

If I skip rewriting and use
http://192.168.1.250/loop/rest/index.php?/admin/logs/file::log-2012-02-14.php

I get what I want,

Here is my rewrite rule:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
 "/(.*)\.(.*)" => "$0",
 "/(css|files|img|js|stats)/" => "$0",
 "^/([^.]+)$" => "/loop/rest/index.php/$1"
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the correct rules:

First of all please make sure that your root directive points to the root of your CI setupd.

```
root /var/www/loop;
```

Then this location directive will work perfectly fine:

```
location /
  {
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I was just having the same issues when testing my codeigniter app on lighttpd

This worked for me:

```
  url.rewrite = (
      ".*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|swf|css|html)$" => "$0",
      "^/(.*)$" => "index.php/$1"
 )
```

maybe you could try this for your setup:

```
 url.rewrite = (
          ".*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|swf|css|html)$" => "$0",
          "^/(.*)$" => "/loop/rest/index.php/$1"
     )
```

Make sure you have uncommented mod_rewrite at the top.. it comes default with a # in front of it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I however found a much simpler rule that works :)